# Class property says "File not Found" ... before even being initialized?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am having the weirdest problem right now ...

I am working on a program that tries to instantiate types (DbContext derivatives) from another project. Because the DbContexts don't simply accept standard parameters but only interfaces from that other projects I had to take some of the other project's assemblies and reference them so I could create dummy-types that implement the interfaces.

The main one is this:

```
class ContextConfigurationDummy:IContextConfiguration
    {
        #region privates
        private ILogger GetLoggerDummy() => new LoggerDummy();
        private ITenantSchemaResolver GetSchemaResolverDummy() => new SchemaResolverDummy();
        private CultureInfo GetUserCulture() => new CultureInfo("en-US");
        private DatabaseMetadata GetDbMetadata() => new DatabaseMetadata();
        private IEntityValidatorFactory GetValidatorFactory() => new ValidatorFactoryDummy();
        #endregion

        public DbConnection GetDbConnection() => new SqlConnection(@"[insert connection string]");
        public RuminantDummy GetRuminant() => new RuminantDummy();
        public Func<CultureInfo> UserCulture { get; set; }
        public Func<DbConnection> Connection { get; set; }
        public Func<IDatabaseMappingRuminant> Ruminant { get; set; }
        public Func<DatabaseMetadata> DatabaseMetadata { get; set; }
        public IEntityValidatorFactory ValidatorFactory { get; set; }
        public Func<ITenantSchemaResolver> TenantSchemaResolver { get; set; }
        public Func<ILogger> Logger { get; set; }
        public ContextConfigurationDummy()
        {
            UserCulture = GetUserCulture;
            Connection = GetDbConnection;
            Ruminant = GetRuminant;
            DatabaseMetadata = GetDbMetadata;
            ValidatorFactory = GetValidatorFactory();
            TenantSchemaResolver = GetSchemaResolverDummy;
            Logger = GetLoggerDummy;

        }
    }
```

The original interface is this:

```
public interface IContextConfiguration
  {
    Func<CultureInfo> UserCulture { get; set; }

    Func<DbConnection> Connection { get; set; }

    Func<IDatabaseMappingRuminant> Ruminant { get; set; }

    Func<DatabaseMetadata> DatabaseMetadata { get; set; }

    IEntityValidatorFactory ValidatorFactory { get; set; }

    Func<ITenantSchemaResolver> TenantSchemaResolver { get; set; }

    Func<ILogger> Logger { get; set; }
  }
```

Everything was working just fine, I didn't look at that part of the code for a while, did quite a few changes to the rest (including to the project itself to adapt it for continuous integration), when I was done I started testing again and, when calling the constructor of ContextConfigurationDummy, I was faced with this:

[image: Image here]

Note how the debugger has not even tried to evaluate it yet! A "normal" error would be that the value is null and after it tries to evaluate it there would be some kind of exception. Not here. There isn't even any file being loaded in this class. Same error for all the following fields

I figured I had to have broken something while working on the project structure, so I remade the entire project, took only the code, re-referenced the assemblies, left everything at default ... and had the exact same error again. So, it has to be the code right?

Well, I reverted to an old commit through git, ran the program, everything working as it should. Great. Checked the code - the relevant parts are exactly the same, except for the Namespaces which were slightly adapted. So, not the code either?

I went back to my current commit and after trying different kinds of ways to reference the external assemblies I tried something else once again: Just for lulz I went into my Main, the Start of the program and tried to instantiate the class with exactly  the same line I used to originally instantiate it: `var dummy = new ContextConfigurationDummy();`

It works. Everything as expected, my class just instantiates normally.

But as if this wasn't weird enough, I'll do you one better:

After calling the method in the main I kept the program running. I got back to the spot where I originally called new ContextConfigurationDummy(). Back into the constructor and ... it works there as well. Took the line out the main - doesn't work. Back in - works again.

I'm beyond stumped, please help. (and don't tell me to clean my solution, I've done so a hundred times and literally remade the entire thing) .

Comment: This looks like a type load exception to me

Comment: How would I go about confirming/debugging that?

Comment: I've had something like this before, the problem was that my projects weren't all set to the same .NET version.  Check that your main project is using the same .NET version as the project whose assembly it is you're trying to load.  Also after a short google, does your updated solution have any projects with the same names as the imported dlls?  It could be looking at the wrong reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm effectively comibining answers from my own experiences and some google-fu here but.

**.NET Version**
Make sure you're using the same .NET version.  I've had it where I've created a new project with an old .NET version and it's screwed me completely with the same issue.

**Assembly Names**

Make sure none of your dlls share the same name with the assembly you're bringing in.  If you have two MyAssembly.dlls it could be looking for the wrong one / version.  Additionally if you've updated the other project at some point, check that all your references are using the same version of a brought in dll.

**Nuget Packages**

Have you updated any Nuget packages in your project that are required by the other assembly also?  (I've had this many times with my unit tests) if so you'll either need to update the other projects nuget packages to the same verison, or possibly add an App.Config file to tell it to use the newer version.

I've never had the same assembly names issue, but I've had the nuget package issue and the .net version issue quite a few times (It's something you just don't think about)